# wordpress featured image

Tags: php

I'm new to Wordpress and I'm trying to create a new theme for it. I've downloaded the latest version (3.2.1) and installed it successfuly. But when I install my wordpress theme (to start to add the PHP) and try to create a new post, what happens is that the Set Featured Image box disappears and it only shows again when I return to the default theme.

Any suggestions for this?
Thank you

Comment: ok..try refer here http://www.hackingethics.com/blog/2010/09/04/how-to-enable-featured-image-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening  is that your theme does not have support for featured image.
What you need to do is add in the functions.php file of your theme the line :

```
if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) {                     
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
}
```

and then you will be able to use featured image in your theme

Comment: This is a duplicate post though!